# Fetching currency name for a provided Locale (Python)

Tags: python, locale

I'm looking for a way to fetch a Currency name for a provided Locale.
For example:

```
currency_name = get_currency_name(locale = "en_US")
print(currency_name) --> "US Dollar"
```

Been scanning the Internet for the answer but can't find anything really helpful.
This is as far as I've come:

```
import pycountry

country = pycountry.countries.get(name='Norway')
currency = pycountry.currencies.get(numeric=country.numeric)
currency_name = currency.name
print(currency_name) --> "Norwegian Krone"
```

Thanks!

Comment: If `locale = "en_US"`, can't you just extract the country `country_code = locale.split("_")[1]` and pass it to `currency = pycountry.currencies.get(alpha_2=country_code)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import locale
import babel
from babel import numbers

def get_currency_name(loc):
  l = locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, loc)
  sym = locale.localeconv()['int_curr_symbol']
  print(babel.numbers.get_currency_name(sym, locale='en_US'))
  locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, l)

get_currency_name('en_US')
get_currency_name('zh')
get_currency_name('de')
```

The output is

```
US Dollar
Chinese Yuan
Euro
```

Comment: Is your question Python 2.7 or Python 3 ++ ? Because I don't see 'numbers' attribute under babel

Comment: It should work now. Need to save the original locale before calling `setlocale()`. Restore the original locale at the end of the functiopn.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot!